# Show only rotation keyframes in the dopesheet?

Tags: modeling, mesh, pose-mode, timeline, dopesheet

Is there a way to show only rotation keyframes in the dopesheet? Or only scale, location ,etc.

Answer (score 3):

In the *Dope Sheet* you can type "loc" in the search field and only the location tracks and keyframes will show up:

[image]

In the *Graph Editor*, if you select the location tracks only and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> the other ones will be deactivated but they will still be shown:

[image]

Comment: I just commented that but your answer looks much prettier +1

Comment: awesome thank u

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann by the way Gordon, do you know why no action can be created for Shader Editor nodes? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @moonboots No sorry, I have no idea. I can access it in the _Non-Linear Animation_, but not the _Action Editor_.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann wow I never even noticed that it was available as a NLA strip, thanks

Comment: @moonboots Ah okay, so maybe that helped. I'm not using actions a lot so I'm not the best consultant for that.

Comment: the weird thing is that you can keyframe a node in the node shader but it's not even available as an action, even weirder is that it's available as a NLA strip

Comment: @moonboots also is there any way i can copy all rotation keyframes for a specific frame? without highlighting them since the dope sheet is too long for me to scroll all the way

Comment: @Murth you can select the keyframes you want and Ctrl C > Ctrl V, is it what you want?

Comment: @moonboots Yes all good thx

Comment: @moonboots the action editing can only be done on "object level actions", ie actions that are directly tied to an object's animation data at the top level.  Shader animation is done at a second level (because it came to Blender later?) under the material property of the object. It's an artificial restriction but I've looked at the code and it would take a lot of changes to make actions more general.

Comment: @Marty Fouts, ok thanks for the precisions, I always wondered why it was not possible, among other things...